# mysql how to query based on latest relationship data

Tags: mysql

I have two table

1. companies
2. company_relocation_histories

Relationship is Company **HAS MANY** Relocation History

Sample data table **companies**

[image]

Sample data table **company_relocation_histories**

[image]

Sample DB -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8uvuc9vvgacz0q/test.sql?dl=0

I want to query all Company that has recently relocate to certain place, for example to FR. Only last location will be counted for.

Expected data is ONLY company id 1 (MIB) will be listed.

Company id 3 (SKD) will be excluded because although they have relocate to FR before, the last relocation is SG.

Here is my take on the SQL query which is not working yet (wrong result). How to solve this? Thanks Stack Overflow!

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `companies` 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   `company_relocation_histories` 
               WHERE  `companies`.`id` = 
`company_relocation_histories`.`company_id` 
                      AND `relocation_location` = 'FR' 
                      AND `id` = (SELECT Max(id) 
                                  FROM   `company_relocation_histories` AS `sub` 
                                  WHERE  sub.relocation_location = 
       company_relocation_histories.relocation_location))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu could use  a subquery for max(id)  and count > 1

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `companies`  c
INNER JOIN company_relocation_histories h on c.id = h.company_id
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT company_id, Max(id)  max_id
    FROM   `company_relocation_histories` AS `sub` 
    group by company_id 
    having count(*) >1
) t on t.company_id = c.id 
        and t.max_id  = h.id 
          and h.relocation_location  ='FR'
```

In this  way you have all the company with more than one location and related to the last location

Comment: Thanks, sadly I have sql syntax error when tried to run this query, not sure where is the problem

Comment: you should show me the exact error message  .. any way i hav update the answer  because someone changed wrongly ..

Comment: hi just tested the updated answer, here is the error

check the right syntax near 'on t.company_id = c.id and t.max_id  = h.id'

Comment: Thanks query working now. However the is problem

1. Relocation is not filtered by specific location, for example FR 

2. It will exclude company that only relocate one time

I modified abit but still no yet solved the problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `companies`  c
INNER JOIN company_relocation_histories h on c.id = h.company_id
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT company_id, Max(id)  max_id
    FROM   `company_relocation_histories` AS `sub`
    where relocation_location='FR'
    group by company_id 
    having count(*) >0
) t on t.company_id = c.id 
        and t.max_id  = h.id
```

Comment: Actually want I want to achieve is:

Get all companies that their company last relocation histories is specific to FR location. The condition relocation_location = FR must be applied to only the last record, if the last record does not match FR, it will be excluded from the result

Comment: thanks answer works almost perfect, I just need to remove the having count(*) >1 else it will exclude company that have only relocation record

Answer (score 1):

Check this query. inner query groups reloaction_histories to get the company_id's which has minimum two or more relocations.

```
select * from companies 
where id in (
  select company_id 
  from company_relocation_histories 
  group by company_id
  having count(*) = 2
);
```

**Edit**: According to OP's comment

```
SELECT * 
FROM   companies 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT company_id 
              FROM   (SELECT company_id, 
                             Lead(relocation_location) OVER(ORDER BY id) x, 
                             Count(*) OVER (partition BY company_id) cnt 
                      FROM   company_relocation_histories) t 
              WHERE  x = 'FR' 
                     AND cnt = 2 
              GROUP  BY company_id);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the query. Actually I also want company that has one relocation, as long as the last relocation is specific place FR.

Your query also include company id 3, even though the last relocation for company id 3 is SG and not FR